# IEnumerable<T>.ToLookup<TKey, TValue>

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, lookup

I am trying to turn an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` into an `ILookup<string, object>` using the following code:

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>()
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("London", null),
    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("London", null),
    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("London", null),
    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Sydney", null)
};

var lookup = list.ToLookup<string, object>(a => a.Key);
```

But the compiler is complaining with:

> Instance argument: cannot convert from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List>'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

and

> 'System.Collections.Generic.List>'
>   does not contain a definition for 'ToLookup' and the best extension
>   method overload
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable.ToLookup(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Func)' has some invalid arguments

and

> cannot convert from 'lambda expression' to 'System.Func'

What am I doing wrong with the lambda expression?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just remove `<string, object>` for the types to be inferred automatically:

```
var lookup = list.ToLookup(a => a.Key);
```

As it really should be:

```
var lookup = list.ToLookup<KeyValuePair<string, object>, string>(a => a.Key);
```

Comment: Aha! Thanks, I didn't realise from the docs that the first parameter is the *Source* type